# How to read text in Coded UI?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

In Coded UI, I have to confirm a particular text is present in text-box.

I am able to reach up to the dialog box and i know how to enter text. However. now i need to read text from the box.

Is there a WinApplication command that can help me to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can just read the text out in the same way that an assertion reads the text to check its value. One way of learning how to do this on *any* control is to use the Coded UI recorder to create an assertion method on the text shown and copy its code. Commonly the assertion will be on the `DisplayText` field. In fact that is a neat way of getting the relevant UI Controls created for you.

The method created  for the assertion (in the `UIMap.Designed.cs` file) will be similar to:

```
public void AssertMethod1()
{
    SomeUIType uITTextItem = this.UISomeWindow.UISomewhere.UITextItem;
    Assert.AreEqual(this.AssertMethod1ExpectedValues.UITextItemDisplayText,
                    uITextItem.DisplayText,
                    "A message for a failed assertion");
}
```

Just copy the whole method into the `UIMap.cs` file, use the commend in the UI Map editor. Then save all the files.

Edit the method that is now in the `UIMap.cs` file to something like the following:

```
public string GetTheUITextItem()
{
    SomeUIType uITTextItem = this.UISomeWindow.UISomewhere.UITextItem;
    return this.AssertMethod1ExpectedValues.UITextItemDisplayText;
}
```

Now the contents of the test can be obtained by calling `GetTheUITextItem()`.